# Simple algorithm for keyword spotting on iOS

Tags: ios, algorithm, cocoa, ios8, speech-recognition

I am working on a game for iPhone that is fully usable by providing YES / NO responses.

It would be great to make this game available to blind users, runners, and people driving cars by allowing voice control. This does not require full speech recognition, I am looking to implement keyword spotting.

I can already detect start and stop of utterances, and have implemented this at https://github.com/fulldecent/FDSoundActivatedRecorder The next step is to distinguish between YES and NO responses reliably for a wide variety of users.

THE QUESTION: For reasonable performance (distinguish YES / NO / STOP within 0.5 sec after speech stops), is `AVAudioRecorder` a reasonable choice? Is there a published algorithm that meets these needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet here is OpenEars, a free and open voice recognition platform for iOS.

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

You most likely DO NOT want to get into the algorithmic side of this. It's massive and nasty - there is a reason only a small number of companies do voice recognition from scratch.

Comment: Great, thank you for the help. I will try implementing this first before going off on the deep end!